# looking up column label corresponding to a value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, lookup

I have a dataframe

```
c.head()
   near_code   code
321  FFZ1988  FFZ1988
322  FFZ1988  FFF1989
323  FFZ1988  FFG1989
324  FFZ1988  FFH1989
325  FFZ1988  FFJ1989
```

And another one:

```
uni.iloc[:,0:7].head()
    near_code     2        3        4        5
319  FFZ1988   FFF1989  FFG1989  FFH1989  FFJ1989
0    FFF1989   FFG1989  FFH1989  FFJ1989  FFK1989
29   FFG1989   FFH1989  FFJ1989  FFK1989  FFM1989
58   FFH1989   FFJ1989  FFK1989  FFM1989  FFN1989
87   FFJ1989   FFK1989  FFM1989  FFN1989  FFQ1989
```

Now for each near_code in 'c', I need to locate the column number of corresponding code in uni. e.g. for first row of c, the answer is 'code' i.e. first locate the 'near_code' = FFZ1988 in uni column 'near_code', and then figure out which column is the corresponding 'code' (=FFZ1988) located in . For second row, the answer is '2', for third, the answer is '3' etc.

I wrote the following to implement this but it is running very slow

```
def find_relative_col(nearest_code,current_code,uni):
    #this function needs to be applied to every row of c to find what is the relative position of code vs near_code
    rel_row = uni[uni.near_code==nearest_code]
    t= rel_row.T
    t.columns =['code']
    t = t.reset_index()
    ans = t[t.code == current_code]['index']
    return ans

ans = c.apply(lambda x: find_relative_col(*x, uni), axis=1)
```

Is there a faster way to do this

Comment: By column number you mean index?

Comment: @GrigoriyMikhalkin yes- kinda like a 'Match' in excel